# Python3 infinite list in list

Tags: python, list

How do I do on python, List in list in list in list... Also I don't know how many list in list there will be. It should look like this:

```
def function(how_many_lists):
    ...
function(2)
#function output: [['hi']]

function(10)
#function output: [[[[[[[[[['hi']]]]]]]]]]
```

I have no clue how to solve this problem on my own. Hope for your help...

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
def function(how_many_lists):
    if how_many_lists == 0:
        return 'hi'
    
    return [function(how_many_lists - 1)]
```

What this does is if how_many_lists > 1 it runs the function again and again (recursion) until it has enough lists inside lists... every iteration it adds a layer

Also, maybe makin the 'hi' an argument could be better... so:

```
def function(how_many_lists, inner):
    if how_many_lists == 0:
        return inner
    
    return [function(how_many_lists - 1, inner)]

function(2, 'hi') --> [['hi']]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Seems problematic if you pass in zero.

Comment: Also, I think `if how_many_lists == 0: return 'hi'` makes more sense and would work logically correct for `function(0)` (instead of failing)

Comment: We can keep with the exception handling and ask that if you pass `string/object/etc`, you can wrap everything with try/except or check the instance.

Comment: altered the solution a bit, now it should be better!